Is rotation invariant under gravitational time dilation?
Imagine a giant ferris wheel with a ten-mile radius on a planet with a strong gravitational field. As it spins, different parts of the wheel experience varying degrees of time dilation due to the planet's gravity.
My question is: does the difference in time dilation between the top and bottom of the wheel create a force, like drag or acceleration, on different parts of the wheel? Would this cause torsion or tension in the wheel's structure?
In simpler terms, does the vertical rotation of the wheel remain unaffected by the variations in time dilation caused by the planet's gravity according to general relativity? More technically and concretely, which is the reason for this example: is vertical rotation an invariant in general relativity or not? And why?

Hey KDP, thanks so much for your answer. I hadn't been able to get to it until now. Not sure I fully understand its implications yet though, English also isn't my primary language so that sometimes makes understanding the difference between angular momentum, angular velocity and acceleration a bit difficult... I posted a reply at first instance, have to think about your answer some more next few days to be honest. I need to see if I understand you correctly. I love the Paddle wheel example though, it's very illustrative. Like Feynman's entropy box

I have extended my answer with an additional experiment for the more general case. Hope you find it interesting :-)


is vertical rotation an invariant in general relativity or not?

If we consider the general case of rotation in any orientation, the answer is no. The large vertical case is difficult to analyse quantitatively, because different parts of the same object experience different time dilation. First consider a small horizontal flywheel as this will make some aspects clear and quantifiable. Imagine the flywheel has very efficient bearings and maintains a more or less constant angular velocity over long time periods. If we measure the angular velocity of the flywheel high in a gravitational field and transport it to a location nearer the gravitational source, an observer travelling alongside the flywheel will measure its rotation rate to be constant. A Schwarzschild coordinate observer that remains in asymptotically flat spacetime far from the gravitational source will measure the flywheel to be rotating slower as it is lowered.
This is not just an artifact of making coordinate measurements. The local proper measurement is not more real than the coordinate measurement. This can be demonstrated as follows: We place an identical flywheel higher up such that local observers say the two flywheels are rotating at the same rate. We connect the two flywheels by a long rod along the axis of rotation that has a clutch mechanism. If the two flywheels are really rotating at the same rate, engaging the clutch should make no difference. At least that is what we would expect in flat space, but in the curved space of a gravitational field, the connecting rod would start twisting as the lower flywheel tries to accelerate the upper flywheel and the upper flywheel tries to slow down the lower flywheel. The connecting rod would eventually break. This is a clear demonstration of the physical reality of gravitational time dilation. Things really do happen slower lower in the gravitational field.
Let's consider an analogy of the huge Ferris wheel in strongly curved spacetime. Imagine we have a large powered paddle wheel that is being driven clockwise, mounted on a tower with the lower portion of the paddle wheel immersed in water . If the paddle wheel was mounted on a paddle boat, it would drive the boat to the right. Since it is mounted on a tower, it tends to bend the tower to the right, creating measurable stresses and strains on the tower. There would also be measurable stresses and strains on the structure of the paddle wheel itself due to the resistance of the water. Back to the case of the large Ferris wheel in strongly curved spacetime, there would similarly measurable stresses and strains on the Ferris Wheel and its supporting structure due to the differences in gravitational time dilation with height, because it would behave like a large paddle wheel immersed in a fluid that is progressively denser and more viscous from top to bottom.
However this analogous viscosity is not exactly like the viscosity of a normal fluid. It only resists changes in  angular velocity. A large frictionless Ferris wheel would maintain its constant angular velocity in the gravity well due to its own angular momentum. The stresses and strains mentioned above would only be present when trying to change the angular velocity of the Ferris wheel.
Addendum: It has occurred to me since writing this answer that there would be bending of the supporting tower even in flat space time due to normal inertia. If we try to get the Ferris wheel to rotate faster in the clockwise direction, there will be an anticlockwise torque reaction trying to bend the tower to the left. In the strongly curved spacetime of a massive body, the additional inertia at the lower part of the Ferris wheel will tend to bend the tower to the right. It is difficult to say what the total effect of these two opposing effects would be and it would be difficult for anyone to come up with a clean exact solution. I think all we can say with any certainty, is that the stresses and strains on the Ferris wheel and its supporting tower would be measurably different in the gravitational field than what they would be in flat spacetime.

I need to wrap my head around this. Are you saying the gradients in gravitational time dilation are equivalent to gradients of resistance in a classical fluid, or not? Secondly, you mention the stresses and strains are only present when trying to change angular velocity of the ferris wheel: do you mean by this it only occurs with acceleration of the angular velocity of the Ferris wheel, or do you mean the rotation as an acceleration per se?

"do you mean by this it only occurs with acceleration of the angular velocity of the Ferris wheel? Yes. I think the wheel would continue to rotate normally if there is no bearing resistance or air resistance, if there is no angular acceleration applied.
